# Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by Php ERROR

Tags: php, header, warnings, runtime-error

Error Is showing in the Header(location......). the error is in the same line where header('location:companies.php?rates=1'); is written

```
"DestinationState"  => $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_stateID'],
    "DestinationZipcode"=> $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['t_zipcode'],
    "Details"           => array('DetailItem' => array( 'Weight' => $_SESSION['order'][$counter]['weight'],'Class' => '55')),
    "Accessorials"      => array('AccessorialItem' => array('Code' => 'LiftgateService')),
    "CODAmount"         => "100",
);

//print('<pre>');print_r($params);die;
   $return = $client->Create(array('request'=>$params));
  // $return = $client->Create($params);
   //$return  = $client->__call('Create', $params);
   //print('<pre>');print_r($return);die;
   $counter=0;
   $_SESSION['Saia'][$counter]['Amount']  = $return->CreateResult->RateDetails->RateDetailItem->Amount;

}
}
}   


header('location:companies.php?rates=1');
?>
```

Comment: do not echo anything before using `header()`. Your program might be printing something on webpage. *Note:* don't even use `<html>` orany other tag if you are to use `header()`

Comment: but i am not echoing anything and its working fine on local but i dont know why its not working on LIVE

Comment: how do you are coming to this code/page? remember to  add `exit()` after every `header()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your first line:

```
<?php ob_start();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing all the leading spaces before header(). Usually there is at least one in the html of the page. I don't see the beginning of the page so I can't help you more.